# Rerunning failed cucumber immediately for a particular exception (ruby)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Background:

We run our cucumber through Jenkins on a Windows VM. We frequently get the following exception (Maybe twice a day, while the suite runs 5 or 6 times):

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)  (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

There is no consistency to this exception. It can and has struck on any step, on any line of code. I do occasionally (though much more rarely) get it locally as well. Cucumber loses all ability to interact with the browser, and all tests afterwards fail.

Within this code

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
```

I want to check if I get that particular exception. If I do, I will kill the chrome browser with a system call, and start it up again (easy part). However, I would like to re-run the scenario that just failed, and then continue on with the rest of the suite. Is this possible?

Side Note: I know the browser is not closed for two reasons. 1. Locally I can see it. 2. trying to start the tests off again results in a failure on the VM, because Chrome is stuck open. The VM is not down. And remember, this occasionally happens locally as well. I have spent a few hours googling for solutions to this problem, and I have found none that work for us.

Versions:

```
Cucumber 1.3.8
ruby 1.9.2
chromedriver 2.4 
chrome 29 (We run tests against a javascript environment that uses GWT, which often breaks with new chrome releases)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the existing rerun formatter:

```
bundle exec cucumber --format rerun --out tmp/failed.txt
```

The failed.txt will store the failed tests along with the line number (And --out is optional). This would retry to run all failed tests after the run.

I am not sure if you can run/call a scenario in between an existing run, so for a broken scenario, restarting chrome -> running the failed test -> continuing might not work since your run is not yet complete.

Though, you can can capture the exception on similar lines (Pseudo code):

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
  e = scenario.exception

  <match e.class with your exception's class>
```

If matched, create a command using cucumber @failed.txt followed by other scenarios you want to run

```
cucumber @failed.txt features/sample.feature -t @test -t @all -n 'test scenario3' ...
```

And then separately fire this command. This will first execute the scenarios in 'failed.txt' file (created when we used the rerun formatter), and then continue on other tests mentioned.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I hate to admit this out in public, where I will most likely be flogged, but some of our tests must be run in a particular order. It is the nature of our data and our service. We have global validation on certain fields, and the entire purpose of our suite is to act like a real user, i.e., start from the beginning and work your way forward. We try to lower dependency between tests as best we can, but as I said, it is the nature of our service.

Comment: I understand, but yes, tests relying on order of run aren't reliable and are strongly discouraged. Maybe you can store the dependent / shared data / states with instance variables, and make your tests more atomic. Apart from that, I don't see a simple way to achieve what you have asked for (since it essentially requires executing cucumber within a cucumber run).

Comment: Even if it were possible to kick the cucumber off within cucumber, I believe that would overwrite my html output anyway, effectively destroying the results of the previous tests. I appreciate your advice in this matter. I may have to settle for running all but the first failed test correctly, although it still could result in the failures of later tests (due to those dependencies I mentioned).

Answer (score -1):

You can just say:

```
fail "Your failure message here..."
```

and you'll get a RuntimeError with that message

Comment: While this is true, it has almost nothing to do with the question.